# How to not paint over certain pixels with repaint()?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I have a JPanel with a paintComponent, and on the panel I paint particles that are moving according to a Timer object. I want some particles (the first ten) to leave a trace, i.e. when they have been painted, I want that position to remain painted. I want to repaint the rest of the particles.

***Is there some way to leave certain components painted while using repaint()?*** I couldn't figure it out, so I tried something like below. But when I uncomment the middle loop, window is just grey and I can't see the particles. Like it is now, it works to my satisfaction. Is it just that it becomes too heavy? When I run it with only 10 particles it still doesn't work.

Also, mysteriously (to me at least), it only seems to work with the repaint() method inside the last loop, but after the last loop. Strange?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //Paints particles in appropriate color.
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Model traced = new Model();   //Initialize a Model-object to keep traced positions
        for(int i=10; i<myModel.size(); ++i){
            Particle particle = myModel.getParticle(i);
            if (particle.isMoving){
                g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
            else{
                g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            }
            int xInt = (int) Math.round(particle.x);
            int yInt = (int) Math.round(particle.y);
            g.fillOval(xInt, yInt, 2, 2);
            }

    /** for (Particle p : traced){   //I try to paint the traced positions
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawOval((int) p.x,(int) p.y,1,1);
        }*/

        for(int i = 0; i<10; ++i){
            Particle particle = myModel.getParticle(i);
            traced.addParticle(particle); // Add the first ten to "traced" model.
            if (particle.isTracked){
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                int xInt = (int) Math.round(particle.x);
                int yInt = (int) Math.round(particle.y);
                g.drawLine(xInt+2, 0, xInt+2, 250);
                g.drawLine(0, yInt+2, 250, yInt+2);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillOval(xInt, yInt, 4, 4);
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillRect(xInt, yInt-12, 8, 12);
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.drawString(Integer.toString(i), xInt, yInt);
            }
            repaint();
        }
```

This is the last couple of errors:

```
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Design a concept of a "particle tail", which allows you store the path of the last `n` particles, which can then be painted when you need them to be

Comment: *"Is there some way to leave certain components painted while using repaint()?"* - No, this is not how painting works, painting by it's nature is destructive. You need to design an algorithm which will allow you determine how many "additional" particles should be painted and where, such as a tail ;) or a degrading cache (which allows entities to be degraded over time) as some ideas

Comment: Nice, thanks for the hint! I will also edit my question with the error message I get.

Comment: Do you have a good idea of what is wrong with the above given the error? I think it has something to do with threading but I know *very* little about that.

Comment: I wouldn't be calling `repaint` from within `paintComponent`, that's a good place to get into trouble

Comment: Ah, okey, I put it elsewhere.

Comment: Consider using a Swing `Timer` to re-schedule repaints

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I will think about that for next time. If the problems persist maybe I will resubmit a better question.

Comment: *"I will think about that for next time."* Cool, I might give your question serious consideration ..next time. Of course, you can [edit] the question right now. *"If the problems persist maybe I will resubmit a better question"* Edit rather than resubmit.. And a tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.